# Is Print Dialog Object from IE Popup treated the same as Excel's Dialog in VBA?

Tags: internet-explorer, vba

I have found a bunch of articles about Excel printing, but what im curious about is how the print prompt works, when a popup to print is created through IE.  Im guessing its not the same reference as you would reference in excel, its going to be a browser object I need to take control of. Essentially right now, I select a link to print and the print dialog pops up. I want to just select "print" automatically.

Comment: Are you automating IE to load pages and then print them?  Whole bunch of missing info here: the context in which you want to print is important...  For example, where are you selecting the link - in IE or in Excel?  Do you have code you can include?

Comment: apologize, i'm automating IE to fill out forms, and the webserver has a "print" button

`.getElementById("button.print").Click`

So when I do that, it automatically loads a print dialog box, just not sure how to interact with the dialog box to hit the print button

Comment: Try using `document.execCommand("Print",[bool display UI])`.  I think if you set that second option to false it may suppress the print dialog.

Comment: Just tested execCommand() and unfortunately seems it always disaplys the print diaolg, even if you set the second parameter to False...

Comment: No worries, thanks for your help! Do you have any good references you can share? You are very knowledgeable...

Comment: Just lucky at Googling most of the time...